# Typescript ignoring `typeRoots` when `noImplicitAny` is set

Tags: typescript

I normally setup my `tsconfig.json` with `strict` set to `true`.  This imply that `noImplicitAny` is also set to `true`.  However, when `strict` is set, typescript seems to ignore my `typeRoots` entry for locally created `*.d.ts` file.  Here is a sample `tsconfig.json` that I use:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2017" ],
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "typeRoots": [ "./typings", "./node_modules/@types" ],
        "types": [ "node" ],
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [ "./src/**/*" ]
}
```

I can add the following to `tsconfig.json` above and it will work:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is a sample project I created to illustrate this problem:

https://github.com/marcoslin/tstyping-test

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`noImplicitAny: false` does not really fix the problem it just ignores it. `template` will be implicitly typed as `any` as no types are found. You get no errors but no type safety either.

The real problem is that you specify `"types": [ "node" ],` this means that only the types for the node module are taken from `typeRoots`. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

The simplest solution is to remove the `types` element from `tsconfig.json`. This tsconfig does not give any errors:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2017" ],
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "typeRoots": [ "./typings", "./node_modules/@types" ]
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [ "./src/**/*" ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I added `"types": [ "node" ]` so that node objects are recognised.  I am checking my other projects to see if it still works after I remove it.

Comment: Indeed this was the solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Although the weird thing is that it it doesn't ignore any other type in the "./node_modules/@types" directory.  Just the ones in the "./typings".

Comment: The docs (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) now say: Keep in mind that automatic inclusion is only important if you’re using files with global declarations (as opposed to files declared as modules). If you use an import "foo" statement, for instance, TypeScript may still look through node_modules & node_modules/@types folders to find the foo package.